# How to add muli select column in inline edit of customer grid for a customer attribue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, multiselect-attribute, customer-grid

I have been trying to add the multi-select option in the inline grid edit of the customer grid for a customer attribute. However, I could find samples for adding multi-select options for inline editing in Magento vendor files. I have tried to add that by referring to this link from Adobe, https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/columns-editor-record/ , but the multi-select values are always returning static which we defined in the ui component and also when we try to save multiple value using this, only value is being saved on database. I have tried to add the class object which returns the all values for that multi select, but it still shows the same.
If anybody knows how to add inline edit for multi-select column in the customer grid, please share with us as that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom JS component only for that particular customer attribute.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <settings>
        <editorConfig>
            <param name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="record" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="fields" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="multiselect" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                                    Vendor_Modulename/js/form/element/customjs
                                </item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/multiselect</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </editorConfig>
    </settings>
    <column name="attribute_name" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
        <settings>
            <editor>
                <editorType>multiselect</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Attribute Label</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

in the custom js file, By referring to multiselect.js from the Magento ui module, I have added the necessary code which is for multi-select and added the extra function 'initObservable' which is defined in select.js in Magento ui. From this function, there is one line that is for setting data for multi-select. Update that with the necessary code.

refer to files from vendor: `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/multiselect.js`
and `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js`